# Fully control Android phone from another Android phone over the Internet

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

Before I write my own app, I want to know if there is an app to fully control one Android phone from another Android phone (over the Internet)?

I need this so that I can remotely start apps, install apps and control apps for a remote Android phone (un/rooted) without requesting permissions. An app to basically do remote screen sharing with full privileges given.

I have used [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) and AirDroid, but I don't like these as the remote device needs to allow permissions.

The usecase is simple: I am giving my mother (not so tech savy), who lives in another country, an Android phone (assuming it will have Internet connectivity over Wi-Fi). I want to be able to fully control her phone from my Android phone (from another country).

Comment: How can it possibly do things that require permissions without *requesting* permissions?  Unless you make a completely insecure Android build from scratch (or root, or make use of massive exploits), that's simply not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [RemoDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.im.RemoDroid). Install it on both system and I believe instructions are in the app.

Comment: The question is fairly easily rephrased into a "how do I" type question, so I don't think that's an issue.  HasH_BrowN is right though, we want answers to be more than a link.  A brief description of how it works or applies to the OP would be helpful.

Comment: @MatthewRead Odd. Try as I might,  There is no **safe** app that provides the *long distance* part. Remodroid is local only, Teamviewer does not allow mobile to mobile connection, and They seem to be the only reliable apps of their type.