# Controlling Android device from Android phone

Tags: remote-control, remote-access, vnc

Kind of related to this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84729/fully-control-android-phone-from-another-android-phone-over-internet).

I want to control my android tablet (galaxy A 9.7 SM-T550, Android 5.0.2) with my Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1) . Both are rooted and I want to be able to control the whole screen of the tablet using WiFi (wifi hotspot from Nexus 5, to use in the car). I have tried Webkey, but the service wont start. Remote Tablet is able to cast the screen, but no input events is registered.

I haven't found any vnc server that is working for android over wifi, just USB. Any ideas on what to use? I don't care that the apps on both side requires permissions per session.

Comment: "Webkey" doesn't work, so which Android is it?

Comment: The developer says [VMLite VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver) works over Wi-Fi as well.

Comment: @Firelord Android versions; Tablet is 5.0.2, N5 is 5.1.1. VMLite VNC Server doesn't start the server when pressing start.