# Using Android phone, how to control someone's Android phone remotely for assistance?

Tags: remote-control

My relative has an Android phone and I have it too. We both are thousands of miles away. She is a new smartphone user, and it is hard for her to learn the skills to use it. She needs help to turn off the music, for example. She called me but I could not help her with instructions. She is alone so I suggested YouTube, etc. I want to teach her how to use the apps.

Is there a way to remotely operate her phone from mine? I want to help her with issues and try to make her independent as far as possible.

Comment: Did you try TeamViewer?

Comment: You should try what @Irfan Latif has suggested. You will be able to connect to your relative's phone and control it from distance.

Comment: Related: [Fully control Android phone from another Android phone over the Internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/84729/44325), [Controlling Android device from Android phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114676/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Comment Instructions (Irfan Latif)

Software Link (Team Viewer - Android)
[TeamViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile)

Guide for Remote Controlling
[Guiding Tech - How to Control Android Remotely Using TeamViewer](https://www.guidingtech.com/32922/control-android-remotely/)